# create text box in document .docx using apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

> I want create a text box in a document .docx but I didn´t find a method
>   that help me do it and any example. Someone know how can i do it?

Answer (score 5):

Inserting a real `Word` Text-box is not fully possible with `apache-poi` until now. A real `Word` Text-box is contained in a `CTShape` from `schemasMicrosoftComVml` or `com.microsoft.schemas.vml`. The XML looks like:

```
<w:r>
 <w:pict>
  <v:shape style="width:100pt;height:24pt">
   <v:textbox>
    <w:txbxContent>
     <w:p>
      <w:r>
       <w:t>The TextBox text...</w:t>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:txbxContent>
   </v:textbox>
  </v:shape>
 </w:pict>
</w:r>
```

As you see the namespaces in  `v:shape` and `v:textbox` are different from the rest.

So if we know and respect this, we can currently insert such `CTShape`. But only inline with the text. Creating a `CTWrap` for this is currently not possible, as far as I know, because the `CTWrap` from  the `schemasMicrosoftComOfficeWord` is not shipped within the poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13-*.jar and the `com.microsoft.schemas.vml` and `com.microsoft.schemas.office` classes from ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar need a `org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader` which is not shipped with version 3.13.

Example for an inline Textbox:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPicture;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTR;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTxbxContent;

import schemasMicrosoftComVml.CTGroup;
import schemasMicrosoftComVml.CTShape;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class CreateWordTextBox {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body text: ");

  CTGroup ctGroup = CTGroup.Factory.newInstance();

  CTShape ctShape = ctGroup.addNewShape();
  ctShape.setStyle("width:100pt;height:24pt");
  CTTxbxContent ctTxbxContent = ctShape.addNewTextbox().addNewTxbxContent();
  ctTxbxContent.addNewP().addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("The TextBox text...");

  Node ctGroupNode = ctGroup.getDomNode(); 
  CTPicture ctPicture = CTPicture.Factory.parse(ctGroupNode);
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  CTR cTR = run.getCTR();
  cTR.addNewPict();
  cTR.setPictArray(0, ctPicture);
    
  doc.write(new FileOutputStream("WordTextBox.docx"));

 }
}
```

But a positioned text-frame is possible:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSdtContentBlock;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPBdr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTBorder;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTFramePr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHAnchor;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STVAnchor;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STXAlign;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STWrap;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STBorder;
/*
To
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTFramePr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHAnchor;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STVAnchor;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STXAlign;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STWrap;
the fully ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar is needed as mentioned in https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025
*/

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordTextFrame {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The body text:");

  CTSdtContentBlock ctSdtContentBlock = doc.getDocument().getBody().addNewSdt().addNewSdtContent();

  CTP ctP = ctSdtContentBlock.addNewP();
  ctP.addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("The TextFrame text...");

  CTPPr ctPPr = ctP.addNewPPr();
  CTFramePr ctFramePr = ctPPr.addNewFramePr();
  ctFramePr.setHAnchor(STHAnchor.TEXT);
  ctFramePr.setVAnchor(STVAnchor.TEXT);
  ctFramePr.setXAlign(STXAlign.CENTER);
  ctFramePr.setWrap(STWrap.AROUND);
  ctFramePr.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(4000));
  ctFramePr.setHSpace(BigInteger.valueOf(400));

  CTPBdr ctPBdr = ctPPr.addNewPBdr();
  CTBorder ctBorder = ctPBdr.addNewLeft(); ctBorder.setColor("000000"); ctBorder.setVal(STBorder.SINGLE); ctBorder.setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(4)); ctBorder.setSpace(BigInteger.valueOf(7));
  ctBorder = ctPBdr.addNewRight(); ctBorder.setColor("000000"); ctBorder.setVal(STBorder.SINGLE); ctBorder.setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(4)); ctBorder.setSpace(BigInteger.valueOf(7));
  ctBorder = ctPBdr.addNewTop(); ctBorder.setColor("000000"); ctBorder.setVal(STBorder.SINGLE); ctBorder.setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(4)); ctBorder.setSpace(BigInteger.valueOf(7));
  ctBorder = ctPBdr.addNewBottom(); ctBorder.setColor("000000"); ctBorder.setVal(STBorder.SINGLE); ctBorder.setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(4)); ctBorder.setSpace(BigInteger.valueOf(7));

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... ");
     
  doc.write(new FileOutputStream("WordTextFrame.docx"));

 }
}
```

This needs the fully ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar as mentioned in https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025.

**Edit**

If we downgrade to ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar - available from [http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.poi|ooxml-schemas|1.1|jar](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.poi%7Cooxml-schemas%7C1.1%7Cjar) - then a free positionable Text-box is also possible with `apache-poi` version 3.13.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPicture;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTR;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTxbxContent;

import schemasMicrosoftComVml.CTGroup;
import schemasMicrosoftComVml.CTShape;
import schemasMicrosoftComOfficeWord.CTWrap;
import schemasMicrosoftComOfficeWord.STWrapType;
/*
To 
import schemasMicrosoftComOfficeWord.CTWrap;
import schemasMicrosoftComOfficeWord.STWrapType;
ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar is needed - available from http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.poi|ooxml-schemas|1.1|jar
*/

import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class CreateWordTextBox {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body text: ");

  CTGroup ctGroup = CTGroup.Factory.newInstance();

  CTShape ctShape = ctGroup.addNewShape();
  ctShape.addNewWrap().setType(STWrapType.SQUARE);
  ctShape.setStyle("position:absolute;mso-position-horizontal:center;margin-top:40pt;width:100pt;height:24pt");
  CTTxbxContent ctTxbxContent = ctShape.addNewTextbox().addNewTxbxContent();
  ctTxbxContent.addNewP().addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("The TextBox text...");

  Node ctGroupNode = ctGroup.getDomNode(); 
  CTPicture ctPicture = CTPicture.Factory.parse(ctGroupNode);
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  CTR cTR = run.getCTR();
  cTR.addNewPict();
  cTR.setPictArray(0, ctPicture);

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... ");
     
    
  doc.write(new FileOutputStream("WordTextBox.docx"));

 }
}
```

---

**Edit**

Using current `apache poi 5.0.0` following is possible:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPicture;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTR;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTxbxContent;

import com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTGroup;
import com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTShape;
import com.microsoft.schemas.office.word.CTWrap;
import com.microsoft.schemas.office.word.STWrapType;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class CreateWordTextBox {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body text: ");

  CTGroup ctGroup = CTGroup.Factory.newInstance();

  CTShape ctShape = ctGroup.addNewShape();
  ctShape.addNewWrap().setType(STWrapType.SQUARE);
  ctShape.setStyle("position:absolute;mso-position-horizontal:center;margin-top:40pt;width:100pt;height:24pt");
  CTTxbxContent ctTxbxContent = ctShape.addNewTextbox().addNewTxbxContent();
  ctTxbxContent.addNewP().addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("The TextBox text...");

  Node ctGroupNode = ctGroup.getDomNode(); 
  CTPicture ctPicture = CTPicture.Factory.parse(ctGroupNode);
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  CTR cTR = run.getCTR();
  cTR.addNewPict();
  cTR.setPictArray(0, ctPicture);

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... ");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("WordTextBox.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: @AxelRicher Thank you. A Free positionable Text-box Is what I needed to overlay an image with text box

Answer (score 0):

For **HWPF** (i.e. the old binary doc format) there is a very rudimentary interface via [`HWPFDocument.getMainTextBoxRange()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument.html#getMainTextboxRange%28%29). I believe it is only suitable for reading, though.

For **XWPF** (the newer docx format that you asked for) it appears that Text Boxes are always embedded in a Drawing (using *DrawingML*; please correct me if I am wrong). At least this is how I interpret clauses 17.3.1.40, 20.4.2.37 and 20.4.2.38 of [ECMA-376, Part 1](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm). Thus, your method of choice should be [`XSSFDrawing.createTextbox()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDrawing.html#createTextbox%28org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor%29). However, I haven't yet come across an easy to use link between this drawing class (which stems from POI's Excel component) and XWPF.

Comment: I didn´t do it with XSSFDrawing.createTextbox()

Comment: @MMora so what did you do then?