# Change font size in text box - apache poi word docx

Tags: apache, textbox, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

I found the answer that explains how to insert a new text box into docx document.

[create text box in document .docx using apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164070/create-text-box-in-document-docx-using-apache-poi/35210029#35210029)

The problem is that I cannot change the font size inside a newly created text box.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: As the linked answer already works on the underlying XML structure, you probably need to create such a document with Microsoft Word and then unzip the .docx file (it's a zip) and look at the xml-files to see where the text size is stored. 

Then you can use the lowlevel POI APIs to add that XML structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference : [create text box in document .docx using apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164070/create-text-box-in-document-docx-using-apache-poi/35210029#35210029)

The `ctTxbxContent.addNewP()` in my code creates a `CTP` object. The `XWPFParagraph` has a constructor `XWPFParagraph(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP prgrph, IBody part)`. So you can get a `XWPFParagraph` from the `CTP` object and then use the default `apache-poi` methods further.

```
...
  CTTxbxContent ctTxbxContent = ctShape.addNewTextbox().addNewTxbxContent();
  XWPFParagraph textboxparagraph = new XWPFParagraph(ctTxbxContent.addNewP(), (IBody)doc);
  XWPFRun textboxrun = textboxparagraph.createRun();
  textboxrun.setText("The TextBox text...");
  textboxrun.setFontSize(24);
...
```