# XWPFRun generating runs with whitespaces trimmed

Tags: java, apache-poi, wordprocessingml

I have developed a Java code which replaces some string patterns in a template and then generates a output docx file, using Apache POI. It was easy to replace the patterns in the headers and paragraphs, but I got an issue while trying to replace inside textboxes. I am using the code provided by Axel Ritcher in [Replace text in text box of docx by using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802369/replace-text-in-text-box-of-docx-by-using-apache-poi), but the problem is that it is trimming some white spaces on each run.

For example:

```
cp -r basedir destination
```

Becomes:

```
cp-r basedir destination
```

The part of the code responsible for doing this substitution is this (The parameters of the function are: doc_buffer is a XWPFDocument, pattern and replacement are both Strings):

```
for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : doc_buffer.getParagraphs()) {
        XmlCursor cursor = paragraph.getCTP().newCursor();
        cursor.selectPath(
                "declare namespace w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' .//*/w:txbxContent/w:p/w:r");

        List<XmlObject> ctrsintxtbx = new ArrayList<XmlObject>();

        while (cursor.hasNextSelection()) {
            cursor.toNextSelection();
            XmlObject obj = cursor.getObject();
            ctrsintxtbx.add(obj);
        }

        for (XmlObject obj : ctrsintxtbx) {
            CTR ctr = CTR.Factory.parse(obj.toString());
            XWPFRun bufferrun = new XWPFRun(ctr, (IRunBody) paragraph);
            String text = bufferrun.getText(0);
            if ((text != null) && (text.contains(pattern))) {
                text = text.replaceAll(pattern, replacement);
                bufferrun.setText(text, 0);
            }
            obj.set(bufferrun.getCTR());
        }
    }
```

If you need any additional information, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I have managed to find the issue that was causing this. I'll post it here so if anyone have the same problem, they can see how I have solved.

The method CTR.Factory.parse used on the example required a String type, but if you check the [XmlObject.Factory docs](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject.Factory.html), there are many parse function which require different types of parameters to use. So I have changed this line:

```
CTR ctr = CTR.Factory.parse(obj.toString());
```

To the method that accepts XMLInputStream as argument, and then created a new InputStream for the XmlObject:

```
CTR ctr = CTR.Factory.parse(obj.newInputStream());
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. That is because `XmlObject.toString` tries creating "pretty-printed" XML. Which seems to mean `<element>-r</element>` instead of `<element> -r </element>`. Not really "pretty" in my opinion. But `XmlTokenSource.xmlText` works as well as `XmlTokenSource.newInputStream` as both not try to be prettier than good.

Comment: Thank you! I discovered this solution but wasn't sure why it worked this way. Now it is more clear to me.