# Could someone share how to delete a paragraph form a textbox

Tags: textbox, apache-poi, xwpf

I am currently working on a project to manipulate Docx file with the Apache POI project.  I have used the api to remove text from a run inside of a text box, but cannot figure out how to remove a paragraph inside a text box.  I assume that I need to use the class CTP to obtain the paragraph object to remove.  Any examples or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not answerable that general. It depends on the kind of the text box and on the condition which paragraph shall be removed. Please ask a more concrete question and do providing the code you have used to remove text from a run inside of a text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Replace text in text box of docx by using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802369/replace-text-in-text-box-of-docx-by-using-apache-poi/46894499#46894499) I have shown how to replace text in `Word` text-box-contents. The approach is getting a list of `XML` text run elements from the `XPath` `.//*/w:txbxContent/w:p/w:r` using a `XmlCursor` which selects that path from `/word/document.xml`.

The same of course can be done using the path `.//*/w:txbxContent/w:p`, which gets the text paragraphs in text-box-contents. Having those low level paragraph `XML`, we can converting them into `XWPFParagraph`s to get the plain text out of them. Then, if the plain text contains some criterion, we can simply removing the paragraph's `XML`.

Source:

[image]

Code:

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;

import  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WordRemoveParagraphInTextBox {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("WordRemoveParagraphInTextBox.docx"));

  for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
   XmlCursor cursor = paragraph.getCTP().newCursor();
   cursor.selectPath("declare namespace w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' .//*/w:txbxContent/w:p");

   List<XmlObject> ctpsintxtbx = new ArrayList<XmlObject>();

   while(cursor.hasNextSelection()) {
    cursor.toNextSelection();
    XmlObject obj = cursor.getObject();
    ctpsintxtbx.add(obj);
   }
   for (XmlObject obj : ctpsintxtbx) {
    CTP ctp = CTP.Factory.parse(obj.xmlText());
    //CTP ctp = CTP.Factory.parse(obj.newInputStream());
    XWPFParagraph bufferparagraph = new XWPFParagraph(ctp, document);
    String text = bufferparagraph.getText();
    if (text != null && text.contains("remove")) {
     obj.newCursor().removeXml();
    }
   }
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("WordRemoveParagraphInTextBoxNew.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

Result:

[image]